# Is it safe to synchronize access to non-Sync data using only a separate atomic variable?

Tags: multithreading, rust, synchronization, atomic, compare-and-swap

Suppose I write my own mutex class, containing data of some arbitrary type `T` and an `AtomicBool` with which I intend to synchronize access to the data:

```rust
struct MyMutex<T> {
    in_use: AtomicBool,
    data: UnsafeCell<T>
}
```

If the only way to access the data from any thread is spin-lock on the `AtomicBool`, is it well-defined to then read and write the data from multiple threads? In other words, is it safe and correct to implement a mutex in this way?

```rust
impl<T: Send> MyMutex<T> {
    fn lock<'a>(&'a self) -> MyMutexGuard<'a, T> {
        while !self.in_use.compare_exchange(false, true, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::SeqCst).is_ok() {
            // spin
        }
        MyMutexGuard {
            in_use: &self.in_use,
            data: self.data.get()
        }
    }
}

struct MyMutexGuard<'a, T> {
    in_use: &'a AtomicBool,
    data: *mut T
}


impl<'a, T> Drop for MyMutexGuard<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if !self.in_use.compare_exchange(true, false, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::SeqCst).is_ok() {
            panic!("Lock wasn't acquired properly");
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Deref for MyMutexGuard<'a, T> { /* ---snip--- */ }
impl<'a, T> DerefMut for MyMutexGuard<'a, T> { /* ---snip--- */ }

unsafe impl<T: Send> Sync for MyMutex<T> {}
```

This approach seems to work, in the sense that I'm able to read and write the data from multiple threads on Rust Playground and don't seem to observe any panics or invalid intermediate states.

[Link to playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a14a7d1e3cf4fb7a1a503a54e3c5ad7)

From a language theoretic point of view of course, "seeming to work" isn't very convincing. Is the data really protected from data races using this approach? Do I need to do extra work to tell the compiler how the data needs to be accessed in sequence with the atomic boolean? Could this break on a different architecture?

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = "Hey earth".to_string();
    let mutex1 = Arc::new(MyMutex::new(data));
    let mutex2 = Arc::clone(&mutex1);
    let mutex3 = Arc::clone(&mutex1);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for _ in 0..100 {
            let mut lock = mutex2.lock();
            lock.push('!');
            lock.push('!');
            println!("thread1: {}", *lock);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    });

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for _ in 0..100 {
            let mut lock = mutex3.lock();
            lock.push('1');
            lock.push('1');
            println!("thread2: {}", *lock);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    });
    
    for _ in 0..100 {
        println!("main:    {}", *mutex1.lock());
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
main:    Hey earth
thread2: Hey earth11
main:    Hey earth11
thread1: Hey earth11!!
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!
main:    Hey earth11!!!!
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!
main:    Hey earth11!!!!!!
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!
main:    Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!
thread2: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!
thread2: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11
main:    Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11!!
thread2: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11!!11
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11!!11!!
thread1: Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11!!11!!!!
main:    Hey earth11!!!!!!!!!!!!11!!11!!11!!!!
[etc...]
```

More generally, I'm interested in whether this approach could be used to e.g. synchronize shared-read/exclusive-write access to separate entries of a shared array, but this smaller example seems like a necessary prerequisitive.

Comment: This approach should be fine. You might want to check out the [spinlock chapter](https://marabos.nl/atomics/building-spinlock.html) of Mara Bos's book, which covers the exact same topic.

Comment: Why won't you use an established spinlock crate, e.g. [`spin::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/spin/latest/spin/type.Mutex.html)?

Comment: "Do I need to do extra work to tell the compiler how the data needs to be accessed in sequence with the atomic boolean?"  You already did, by specifying `SeqCst` ordering.  In fact, even AcqRel suffices here.

Comment: Thanks all. I think what I struggled to understand is how atomic operations affect the order of other non-atomic operations. Mara Bos' book is excellent. I'm reinventing the wheel here to understand it for myself. Ultimately, your feedback and tips helped me to extend this to my ultimate goal of writing a wait-free thread-safe slice, so thanks a lot! https://github.com/timstr/atomicslice I can write an answer below to summarize later, if nobody beats me to it